# Hidden Cron in the Webserver cant find out where its located ...?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, cron

in my dedicated server i have i have hidden cron job (one of the cpanel user account is using) running which is not showing up anywhere (installation is based on cpanel/whm)

first i had a look at the

```
crontab -e
```

to see if there no its not there,  then i had a look at the cpanle account cron files

```
/var/spool/cron/username
```

its not there either,

nor

```
/etc/crontab
```

nothing in

```
/var/logs/cron
```

i can see it running everyday (becaue i see the emails going) but i cant findout where is this coming from.

Also another strange thing i noticed is the usual setup for

doesn't work but

```
30 9 * * 3 php /home/username/public_html/protected/cron.php Weekly
```

this works

```
15 4 * * * lynx -dump 'http://www.xxx.com/admin/counts.php'
```

not sure what is this problem and where its coming from and no idea on whats going on in the crons...

any luck ?

Comment: If it's a cron job it has to be triggered by something in the crontabs directory (`/var/spool/cron/*`) or the system crontab (`/etc/crontab`, possibly `/etc/cron.d` on Linux systems). You may also have a cron job that runs other tasks...

Comment: if it's really run by cron, check the cron log /var/log/cron

Comment: i checked the /var/log/cron there is no log there then i checked the ect/crontab there is nothing there too ... no such file called etc/cron.d  hmmm still a mistry ...

Answer (score 1):

The periodic task/s might not be running through cron. If cron isn't logging them and they're not showing up in `/var/spool/cron` or `/etc/cron.d`, then check if any other task scheduling daemon (such as monit) is running.

If you find it/them running then you can look up its(the task scheduling daemon's) configuration to find possible suspects.

Answer (score 0):

check `/var/log/syslog` (in Ubuntu) if its a cron it should get listed there, you might also want to grep the command which is executing in syslog that would tell you how is it getting executed

Answer (score 0):

Also don't forget others like **logrotate.d** because they may include scripts run before/after each log rotation